# What is : "Element extends past end of object" ? How can I fix it?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I'm getting the error: "Element extends past end of object" in this route.  I googled it but didn't find much of anything.  Does anyone know how I can fix it and what exactly the problem is?

Thanks!

```
app.get('/item/:name', function(req, res) {
//  console.log("Ok, we\'re in app.get \'item/:name\', let's debug");
    console.log(req.params.name); //== "something" here
    Item.findById(req.params.name, function(err, doc) {
      debugger;
      if (err){
        console.log(err); // =="Element extends past end of object"
        res.send(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log(" in the app.get/item:name db.query.  The item is: " + item);
  //    debugger;
        res.render('items/view'); 
      }
  });
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are just using the wrong method, `findById` only searches by ObjectID. In your context (i don't really know that you are sending in req.params.name), i don't think you should be searching by ID.

Try using `findOne` instead (replace [yournamefield] with the corresponsing fieldname inside your Item model):

```
app.get('/item/:name', function(req, res) {
//  console.log("Ok, we\'re in app.get \'item/:name\', let's debug");
    console.log(req.params.name); //== "something" here
    Item.findOne({ [yournamefield]: req.params.name }, function(err, doc) {
      debugger;
      if (err){
        console.log(err); // =="Element extends past end of object"
        res.send(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log(" in the app.get/item:name db.query.  The item is: " + item);
  //    debugger;
        res.render('items/view'); 
      }
  });
});
```